# Read text file into variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I've got a text file Text.txt

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

without any white spaces and would like to transfer the content to a variable.
When I use

```
value=$(<Text.txt)
echo $value
```

it will print out as the following:

```
abcde fghij klmno
```

What can I do that the content in the variable is like that in the text file, so

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

?

Comment: `echo "$value"` or `printf "%s" "$value"`